# What does "for a mile" mean in this sentence of Thoreau?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

In [*Slavery in Massachusetts*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/70123/pg70123-images.html#Page_97), Thoreau writes:

> But it chanced the other day that I scented a white water-lily,
> and a season I had waited for had arrived. It is the emblem of purity.
> It bursts up so pure and fair to the eye, and so sweet to the scent,
> as if to show us what purity and sweetness reside in, and can be extracted from,
> the slime and muck of earth. I think I have plucked the first one that has opened **for a mile**.

What does *for a mile* mean in this sentence? I looked up
[*for*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/for#Preposition) in a dictionary, and methinks the author might mean the first lily that he came across,
and that was opened, after walking a mile. Or does Thoreau mean something else here?

Comment: While your other questions about Thoreau concerned the features of the nineteenth century English that are not regularly seen nowadays, or the puzzling idiosyncrasies of his style, there is nothing particularly outdated or puzzling about his use of this phrase.

Comment: It's a metaphorical mile — a long distance: the first one that has opened as far as the eye can see (or the nose can smell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoreau is telling you how far he has walked before seeing the lily.

**For** a mile = over the distance of a mile.

The OED:

> **For** (*prep.*)
>
> **VIII.** Expressing duration and extension.
>
> **24. Marking an amount of spatial extension: over, over the space of, to the extent of.**
>
> 1978   Nature 5 Jan. 50/2   *The Bathurst and McDonald faults..are
> major sinistral and dextral strike-slip fault systems that extend
> **for** hundreds of kilometres.*
>
> 2009   Argus (Sussex) (Nexis) 20 June   *Turn left along the drive
> **for** 100 yards and, just before a house called Murrells, take the right turning*

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct. "for" has many meanings but here is the relevant one:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)
> *for*: preposition
> towards; in the direction of:
> *They looked as if they were heading for the train station.
>
> Just follow signs for the museum.
>
> This time tomorrow we'll be setting off for the States.
>
> It says this train is for (= going to stop at) Birmingham and Coventry only*.

Hence, we have the implication that Thoreau was walking in some direction towards the point where he found the flower in bloom, at which point he would have walked a mile.